# how to fill javascript text box with selenium and python (without send_keys)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to enter a value into a field

I find the element by:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cell--gE-Ez1qtyIA"]')
```

And I do this to display the text and click:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cell--gE-Ez1qtyIA"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cell--gE-Ez1qtyIA"]').text
```

So far so good, but I use this code when I want to send a value to this field:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cell--gE-Ez1qtyIA"]').send_keys('test')
```

Nothing happens and the field value does not change

Comment: better create minimal working code with real URL so we could run it and see this problem

Answer (score 1):

Since we are unaware about the nature of the text box you are trying to access, there are some possibilities because of which you are facing this situation. The `send_keys()` works on all the text box which ever you use. Look for the points below and try applying it on the element:

1. The element is not extracted properly, try some other locator like id, name, css_selector.
2. The element is not ready to use, put some explicit wait and check for presence and visibility of element.

A sample code can be using explicit wait:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(("xpath", "//*[@id='cell--gE-Ez1qtyIA']")))
element.send_keys("test")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `javascriptexecutor` instead of `sendkeys`

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
je.executeScript("document.getElementById('IDofElement').setAttribute('value', 'your value here')");
```